# How can I make a POWER-LED Lamp?

Tags: led, mains, capacitive, transformerless

What is the best way to light 10 POWER-LEDs with AC mains (220V)?

(I want to make an LED lamp.)

---

Here is more info:

I have 10 of these POWER-LEDs:

[image: 1W POWER LED]

- Product Chip: 40x40 mil
- Chip Brand: EVERLIGHT-Taiwan
- Lumens: 90-100LM
- Voltage: 3.2-3.4V
- Current: 300-350mA
- Viewing angle: 140 degrees

And I have soldered all of them in series (with heat sink).

Comment: Yes, you can, but that would be a very bad idea for safety.

Comment: Welcome to this community. Unfortunately there is not enough information to give you an answer and you question may be closed quickly because of this. Please edit your question and add more information about your exact LED model for instance.

Comment: Dear Vladimir Cravero. It will be a lamp. A light bulb. and cannot be touched . So there is no reason to be worried about its safety.

Comment: @BlueSky When dealing with AC mains, safety is always a factor.  Don't take AC mains lightly.

Comment: Thank you all . But, could you please answer my question ?

Comment: The first comment (from @VladimirCravero) answers your question exactly.

Comment: You answered the question yourself. "capacitive transformerless power supply". What do you mean "it can't be touched"? Do you know that with that kind of power supply one of the "low voltage" lines might be the HOT wire? If you can tell 100% that your device is safe from this pov then you can design the capacitor psu. If you can't design it then I think you can't be 100% it will be safe, hence I am not answering. Someone will anyway.

Comment: My English is not well ('it cant be touched' means nobody will touch the tracks on the PCB). I thought you have realized it ! You say that it's dangerous? So I'll never use Capacitive Power Supplies . Now I edited my question . please read it if you want.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. you must define "the best"! cheaper?...

Comment: not cheaper. It should be as compact as possible.

Comment: Your English is pretty good! at least better than mine. Why don't you use prepared LED driver?

Comment: @Roh what are they?  and I wanted to talk in chat rooms but I did't have enough reputation (20)!

Comment: For example this: http://eshop.eca.ir/%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%88%D8%B1-power-led/2751-led-driver-6-10x1w-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87.html Damn, I had forgotten it!

Comment: and check out these three link for reputation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast and http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @Roh No resistors needed in series??

Comment: nope, there is no need to extra resistor.(when input is 220AC and you have 10 LED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten in series will require 32V-34VDC at 300-350mA, or worst case just about 12W. You'll need a stepdown transformer from 240VAC to 36VAC at 350mA, and you'll need a half-wave rectifier (do NOT use a full-wave rectifier unless you use a 24V transformer!) good for 50V @ 350mA, and you'll need one stabilizing power resistor capable of dropping about 2V at 350mA (about 5.7 ohms), rated for 12W.

I mentioned a full-wave rectifier. You COULD use a full bridge rectifier with a 24VAC transformer secondary - that'd get you 24*1.414!=34V, but then you wouldn't have any room for the stabilizing power resistor so you'd be running on blind faith unless you removed ONE of those LEDs from the circuit and replaced it with an equivalent power resistor.

Do remember... this whole assembly will generate a significant amount of heat, and you have to get rid of that heat somehow or you'll overheat the LEDs and the resistor.

Comment: No capacitors needed? I'll use a 24VAC transformer and 9 LEDs.  then how much resistance should the stabilizer resistor have ?

Comment: Tthe stabilizer resistor should have about 87.5 Ohms. So Is this [schematic](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/20/e653c09ff438966013d4a8bfadaf352e/led.jpg) the answer ??

Comment: Nearly. It'll need a stepdown transformer between the 240VAC and the bridge rectifier, though.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add transformer in schematic.